# RegEx: how to don't match a repetition

Tags: regex

I have followings String:

```
test_abc123_firstrow
test_abc1564_secondrow
test_abc123_abc234_thirdrow
test_abc1663_fourthrow
test_abc193_abc123_fifthrow
```

I want to get the abc + following number of each row.
But just the first one if it has more than one.

My current pattern looks like this: `([aA][bB][cC]\w\d+[a-z]*)`

But this doesn't involve the first one only.

If somebody could help how I can implement that, that would be great.

Comment: Try `^.*?([aA][bB][cC]\d+[a-z]*)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works great !

Comment: Do you need to assert a leading '_' perhaps to avoid 'false' positives like 'dabc1test_abc193'? Same goes for trailing underscores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^.*?([aA][bB][cC]\d+[a-z]*)
```

Note the removed `\w`, it matches letters, digits and underscores, so it looks redundant in your pattern.

The `^.*?` added at the start matches the

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `([aA][bB][cC]\d+[a-z]*)` - Capturing group 1: `a` or `A`, `b` or `B`, `c` or `C`, then one or more digits and then zero or more lowercase ASCII letters.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following regex:

`^.*?([aA][bB][cC]\d+)`

1. Use `^` to begin at the start of the input
2. `.*?` matches zero or more characters (except line breaks) as few times as possible (lazy approach)
3. The rest is then captured in the capturing group as expected.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZvdSXX/1)